# How to create a procedure in XSJS dynamically in HANA

Tags: hana, xsjs

I have created an application in which I'm calling XSJS file from the browser and in that XSJS file I am calling a normal SQL procedure. In that procedure after some validations I'm calling R procedure. My requirement is to create that R procedure in the user schema when the user calls the XSJS file. And call statement for that R procedure should be updated in SQL procedure. So basically every time a user calls XSJS file the R procedure should be dropped and created again in the user schema. I am using SAP HANA studio latest version.

Comment: Not quite sure I see a question here. What exactly do you want to know? Where is the problem for you? Creating procedures? Calling those procedures?

Comment: Why do you need to recreate the procedure? Usually creating database artifacts during runtime is not the best idea.

Comment: Definitely not the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute dynamic SQL in SAP HANA, you can use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** SQL command that will work in read and write procedures. You can build SQL query to create a new procedure in xsjs, send this query to a read and write procedure in which you have to use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE QUERY** to get your procedure created and same can be done for deletion as well.